# LIMIT and JOIN order of actions

Tags: sql

I have a query which includes `LIMIT` to the main table and `JOIN`.

My questions is that: what is coming before? the query finds the `x` rows of the `LIMIT` and then doing `JOIN` to these rows **or** doing first the `JOIN` on the all rows and just after that `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` Applies to the query to which it is applied. It will be applied to the query AFTER the `JOIN`s in *that* query, but if the derived table is `JOIN`ed to *other* tables, that/those `JOIN`(s) comes after.

e.g.

```
SELECT ..
  FROM (SELECT ..
          FROM TABLE1 T1
          JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON ..
         LIMIT 10) X
  JOIN OTHERTABLE Y
 LIMIT 20;
```

- The `JOIN` between T1 and T2 occurs first
- `LIMIT` 10 is applied to result from the previous step, so only 10 records from this derived table will be used in the outer query
- `LIMIT` 20 is applied to the result of the `JOIN` between X and Y

Although LIMIT is a specific keyword for **PostgreSQL**, **MySQL** and **SQLite**, the TOP keyword and processing in **SQL Server** works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

> doing first the JOIN on the all rows and just after that LIMIT